# Need to remove duplicate keys without removing entire dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, key-value

I want to remove a duplicated key "John Doe" from a dictionary.

Dictionary

```
info = [{"author": "John Doe", "book": {"title": "Getting started with Golang", "rating": 4.2, "category": "programming"}},
        {"author": "John Doe", "book": {"title": "Best practices with Reactjs", "rating": 4.4, "category": "front-end"}}]
```

I want the result to look something like this:

```
test = {info[0]["author"]: [info[0]["book"], info[1]["book"]]}
```

My attempt, except this removes the entire second dictionary.

```
aList = {}
final = []

for i in info:
    for values in i.values():
        if values not in aList.values():
            aListi["author"] = values

print(aList)
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you what you want;

```
info = [{"author": "John Doe", "book": {"title": "Getting started with Golang", "rating": 4.2, "category": "programming"}},
        {"author": "John Doe", "book": {"title": "Best practices with Reactjs", "rating": 4.4, "category": "front-end"}}]

authors = {}

for entry in info:
    authors.setdefault(entry['author'], []).append(entry['book'])

print(authors)

# Output
{'John Doe': [{'title': 'Getting started with Golang', 'rating': 4.2, 'category': 'programming'}, {'title': 'Best practices with Reactjs', 'rating': 4.4, 'category': 'front-end'}]}
```

This uses [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) which just initializes a specific key, in this case your author name, and `append` the item to the list.

Comment: Updated it with a link to `setdefault`, but to sum it up it similar to how `get` works but it also populates the item with a default. Would be great if you could mark it as the answer if you found it helpful. Thanks !

Comment: Just a little question, did .setdefault(entry["author] remove the duplicates?

Comment: It shouldn't, it will checks whether that key, `entry['author']`, exists. If it does not exists it will populate with your default value, in our case `[]` (an empty list), otherwise it will just return the current values under the `entry['author']` key.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
print({k: [book["book"] for book in g] for k, g in groupby(info, lambda x: x["author"])})
```

Output:

> {'John Doe': [{'title': 'Getting started with Golang', 'category':
>   'programming', 'rating': 4.2}, {'title': 'Best practices with
>   Reactjs', 'category': 'front-end', 'rating': 4.4}]}

Comment: Currently I'm trying to not use libraries that help solve problems like this. I'm beggineer. Thanks for the help still

Comment: I think you can use @fixatd solution then.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```py
new_dict = pd.DataFrame(info).groupby(['author'])['book'].\
           apply(lambda x : x.tolist()).\
           to_dict()

new_dict

{'John Doe': [{'title': 'Getting started with Golang',
   'rating': 4.2,
   'category': 'programming'},
  {'title': 'Best practices with Reactjs',
   'rating': 4.4,
   'category': 'front-end'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and to get the key I suggest using `operator.itemgetter`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

info = [{"author": "John Doe", "book": {"title": "Getting started with Golang", "rating": 4.2, "category": "programming"}},
        {"author": "John Doe", "book": {"title": "Best practices with Reactjs", "rating": 4.4, "category": "front-end"}}]

result = {k: [d['book'] for d in g] for k, g in groupby(info, itemgetter('author'))}
```

---

```
{'John Doe': [{'title': 'Getting startedwith Golang', 'rating': 4.2, 'category':'programming'},
              {'title': 'Best practices with Reactjs', 'rating': 4.4, 'category': 'front-end'}]}
```